# How do I know which environment a previous application version was deployed to?

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk

In AWS Elastic Beanstalk, if I navigate to "Application versions" for a particular application, the "Deployed to" field is empty for most of the versions, even though they were all deployed to an environment.  I thought maybe the field was empty if the value was the same as the *previous* record, but I don't think the top record always contains a value.  Is there any way I can determine to which environment an application version was deployed from the web UI?

[image]

Answer (score -1):

If you have CI (or do it manually) you could deploy with message

```
eb deploy -m "deploy to stage"
eb deploy -m "deploy to production"
```

This message should be displayed in the description column